Tryin to understand bloc, are you supposed to create multiple instances of the same bloc?
If you have a to-do list, is it okay to create multiple instances of the same bloc like this, where im giving each to-do it's own instance and state. Or am I supposed to put all of them inside it's own bloc?
todos.map((e) {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
    child: BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => TodoBloc(),
      child: TodoItem(todo: e),
    ),
  );
}).toList(),


what is the reason to give own bloc instance to every item?
why you need it? does every item has its own functionality and bloc logic will be different for every item?

Suppose both scenarios works, so what is the difference ?
The difference actually related to performance, imagine that:
Each task has its own Bloc object that manages its state and so on.
todos.map((e) {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
    child: BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => TodoBloc(),
      child: BlocConsumer(//to use the provided bloc

           child: TodoItem(todo: e)),
    ),
  );
}).toList(),

So, every task requires a Bloc provider and a Bloc Consumer, which equal to NoTasks * 2 (objects in device memory).
The other scenario, is to provide a Bloc object for all of the existing tasks to manage their state,
BlocProvider(
BloConsumer(
List<Tasks>

// if a task is checked to be marked completed
// pass its name or id to the bloc to change its state
)
)

So, only two objects in memory manages the states of the whole tasks, which increases the performance.
It's completely revolves around the performance.
Hope it helps you.

I thought that for example, an extension of the bloc state could be CompletedTodo, but when it's a list, some of them will be completed and some will not. Which means it won't work. Does this mean I'm misinterpreting the different states that should be created for a bloc?

yes, tasks have different states(new, completed and archived) is that correct !. so what happen when you check a task to be completed using a check box for example, you just modify this task within your list and emit a new state that describe what happened then update that task in db or whatever. (one bloc manages all tasks) ,at last providing a unique bloc for each task is so expensive.
